# Greendao - How to compare string column ignoring case?

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I have a query in sqlite:

```
select * from table where upper(name) = "ABC";
```

Is there a function in greendao to execute same query?

Answer (score 3):

You can use LIKE for that.
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE flow LIKE "Tiroirs"
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE flow LIKE "TirOirS"
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE flow LIKE "tiroirS"
```

The three examples above have the same result in sqlite (mysql also, I don't know if all DBs have the same behaviour). Then you can use the equivalent for GreenDao :

```
priceDao.queryBuilder().where(PricesDBDao.Properties.Flow.like(flow))
```

Comment: remember to add "%" if you're expecting a behaviours like "contains", "startsWith" or "endsWith". i.e: priceDao.queryBuilder().where(PricesDBDao.Properties.Flow.like("%"+flow+"%"))

Answer (score 1):

Try like this RAW Query

```
Query query = userDao.queryBuilder().where(
new StringCondition("(select * from table where upper(name) = "ABC")").build();
```